# Google Map API Not displaying Markers JavaScript

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to grab latlng co-ords from my database to display them on a webpage which will dynamically update when a user searches for something specific but they aren't showing up at all.

```
<?php
    include_once '../db/dbconnect.php';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM property WHERE city='Sheffield' AND type='House'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($num_rows > 0){
       for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++){
            $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
            $location[] = $row[3].','.$row[6].','.$row[7].','.($i+1);
      }
   }

?>
```

I'm having problems with fetching the data from the database as $location doesn't seem to have any values inside of it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, including the output of the PHP to the browser.

Comment: I have narrowed down the problem: 
var locations = <?php echo json_encode($location); ?>;

when used in browser translates to 

var locations = null;

Answer (score 0):

I can see issue in your HTML code structure, you have started div tag but it ended after your javascript code. so please start div and end that div then write youyr javascript code as mentioned below.

```
<div id='map'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = <?php echo json_encode($location); ?>;

    var map;
    function initMap() {
     if(typeof locations !== "undefined")
     {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 53.3811, lng: -1.4701},
        zoom: 13

        });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;
    alert(locations.length);

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
        loc_array = locations[i].split(",");

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(loc_array[1], loc_array[2]),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(loc_array[0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        } 
      }
    }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCtf7Q1QeO9cQfwsBo7FQ-g3en_zJbk8Iw&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

I am not sure about this will work.

You php code should be

```
<?php
include_once '../db/dbconnect.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM property WHERE city='Sheffield' AND type='House'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$location=array();

if(mysql_num_rows($result)> 0){
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $location[] = array($row['lat'],$row['lng']);
}}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I originally had it set up like that but in my frustration started to move things around.

Comment: then provide your source code from browser (not from inspect element) related to this code.

Comment: sheffield.php:105 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Is this what you mean? Sorry I am new to Stack Overflow

Comment: var locations = <?php echo json_encode($location); ?>; 

After this line put

alert(typeof locations);

let me know what is alerting?

Comment: i think you get undefined or null, please check php variable $location by print_r($location); die();

Comment: var locations has type object and using print_r die(); causes the webpage to be blank whitespace.

Comment: means have issue in your php code for fetch lat long from database

Comment: Do you have any idea of what the issue may be? I can fetch the data as the data about the properties is being displayed on the page.

Comment: what is structure of property  table in database?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/6139a8d2362e9d1bb48d447b4175cc99

This is a link to the structure of the table

Comment: if you like my help please upvote it, and other ansers from my side please up vote :)